# Likelihood ratio test of log normal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, likelihood-ratio

$X_{1},X_{2}, … , X_{n}$ be a random sample from a $(\theta, 1)$ distribution. Instead of observing
$X_{1},X_{2}, … , X_{n}$, $Y_{1},Y_{2}, … , Y_{n}$ was observed where $Y_{}= ^{X_{i}}$. Find the critical region of the likelihood ratio test, to test the 
hypothesis $_{0}: \theta= 1$ against $_{1}: \theta\neq 1$ based on the random sample $Y_{1},Y_{2}, … , Y_{n}$
(for some $c_{1} \leq c_{2,}$).

Can I just say that log normal distribution belongs to exponential family and therefore the rejection region would be $log\sum Y_{i} \leq c_{1}$ or $log\sum Y_{i} \geq c_{2}$.

I initially tried taking the ratio (as in definition of LRT) but got stuck. Is the region obtained using the sufficient statistic as stated above, the right approach?

Comment: Why not just re-express the data in terms of their logarithms and use a standard Normal-theory test??

Answer (score 1):

- $\log\sum\limits_i Y_{i}$ is not a sufficient statistic for this $Y$; nor is $\sum\limits_i  Y_{i}$.
- $\prod\limits_i  Y_{i}$ is a sufficient statistic,
- its logarithm $\sum\limits_i \log Y_{i}$ is also a sufficient statistic.

Either of these latter two could be used to define a rejection region.  The latter might be easier to explain, since $\log Y_{i}$ has a normal distribution; indeed if you observe $Y_i$ then you know the value of $X_i= \log Y_i$